# Exporting "Posts" from Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

I want to export all posts from Dynamics CRM. I've set up an Advanced Find to give me all Manual Posts, but I don't get the "export to Excel" on the dialog.

Can this be enabled?

Comment: System Administrator, System Customizer and lots more. Is there a particular role that controls this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XrmToolBox Plugin: Export to Excel.

Please validate.

Comment: Please explain the function so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!